# refreshing list view dont work after i remove item from listview

Tags: android, listview

my application have a bug. i add item in my list view correctly and list view refresh automatically for deleting item from list view it work correct too, but if I add items and delete then the refreshing not work.sorry for my English if there is a question please ask in comments.in fact i want to add item in a list view and push a button so i expect the list view refresh. so  i use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and if I click on an item it remove from list. my problem is automatic refresh don't work after i delete an item from list.
the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />


<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

the java code:

```
    public class Test extends ListActivity {

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String       bbc  = "";
String       bbc2 = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
    final Spinner aminika = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_test);
    //for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_test));
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    aminika.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    //for listview
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    //=================================================
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //=====
            bbc = String.valueOf(aminika.getSelectedItem());
            bbc2 = edit.getText().toString();
            list.add(bbc + " " + bbc2);
            edit.setText("");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    //=============================
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Test.this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to remove!")
            .setCancelable(true)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, close
                    // current activity
                    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                    list.remove(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
    //=====================================
}
}
```

what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create and set a new adapter in onListItemClick. Instead of

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

try

```
final ListAdapter adapter = l.getAdapter();
```

The way you do it, you call notifyDataSetChanged() in onClick on the old adapter instance (which isn't the ListView's adapter, anymore, because you created and assigned a new one in onListItemClick).
This would explain why updating the ListView (after adding an element) doesn't work after the first removal. I haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a array of fixed strings, and each click, you populates the list again

Here:

```
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

setListAdapter(adapter);
//=============================
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        Test.this);
```

I suggest you use an arraylist to save the old and new data during the current session.
This list is to be persisted or is to go back to the original each time the activity is open?

Comment: I don't save any change and I want it goes back to original form